# How to troubleshoot Exim problems?

Tags: exim, dkim

I'm having difficulty making Exim add DKIM signatures to outgoing email. Judging by all the questions about that on the web, I'm not alone. But the answers are all of the form "Try this ...", "This worked for me ..." followed by various ways of setting DKIM_DOMAIN, DKIM_SELECTOR, etc applicable to one situation.

But there is a more general problem. The Exim macro language for setting these variables is pretty arcane. How do I display the results? Is there a way of making Exim dump the actual calculated values of DKIM_DOMAIN, DKIM_SELECTOR etc into the log file? That's what we really need.

Comment: What exim version and config files you use? https://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-dkim_spf_srs_and_dmarc.html   https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-log_files.html 15. Reducing or increasing what is logged

Comment: @gapsf : Version 4.94, non-split configuration. The section you link to lists a lot of things that can be put in the log but none of them seem relevant to showing the results of calculating variables. For example I have: DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lookup{$domain:$h_from:}lsearch,ret=key{/etc/exim4/dkim/tags}} and then that gets used in more expressions for DKIM_SELECTOR and DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY. I need to be able to debug these expressions. I'm not looking for a recipe for this week's problem, I'm looking for a way to inspect these intermediate results to be able to diagnose such problems in general.

Comment: Try thisv stop exim service and then start manually as root `exim -bd -d+all` > /var/log/exim-debug.log 2>&1, send mails then stop and check log output

Answer (score 0):

Try this: stop exim service and then start manually as root `exim -bd -d+all` > /var/log/exim-debug.log 2>&1, send your mails then stop and check log output.

The available debugging categories (i.e. lookup - general lookup code and all lookups)
https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html

Comment: Tried this (again) - as expected, it is not useful. It dumps a lot of stuff, but not the value of DKIM_DOMAIN or any of the other variables.

Comment: Did you ask exim mailing list?

Comment: Did you try debug_print in transports? Could you provide dkim related conf of your exim